# Informix: Inserting values into tables using input parameters with EXECUTE USING

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

We're having a situation where we need to insert values into multiple tables using a stored procedure similar to this:

```
DROP TABLE informix.myTable;
GO
CREATE TABLE informix.myTable (id SERIAL NOT NULL, my_field DECIMAL(7,0))
GO
DROP PROCEDURE informix.Insert_Into_Table;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE "informix".Insert_Into_Table (pTable_name CHAR(30), pValue DECIMAL(7,0))
RETURNING INTEGER;

    -- EXECUTE informix.Insert_Into_Table('myTable', 12345)

    DEFINE cust_qry VARCHAR(250);
    DEFINE new_id INTEGER;

    LET cust_qry = 'insert into informix.' || pTable_name || ' ( my_field ) values ( ? )';
    PREPARE stmt_id FROM cust_qry;
    EXECUTE stmt_id USING pValue;

    SELECT  DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1') 
    INTO    new_id
    FROM    systables WHERE owner = 'informix' AND tabname = pTable_name;

    FREE stmt_id;
    RETURN new_id;
END PROCEDURE;
```

We're getting a syntax error in the EXECUTE USING line (it compiles commenting that line).

We need to retrieve the SERIAL id from the procedure, and it's desirable to use the USING clause since there are >100 values (like pValue) in the real world situation.

IBM online docs show EXECUTE USING host variables but we couldn't find any examples using stored procedure parameters.

Informix Version: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC10WE

Any pointers on how to solve that error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I got the impression that you can't not prepare a SQL statement with the 'INTO' keyword in an SPL. Most of the documentation about Dynamic SQL is for ESQL/C and 4GL.  'EXECUTE USING' is valid within a ESQL/C program, but it's not allowed in SPL.   The closer you have is 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' but it doesn't take parameters but, if you are already building a string  (table_name) you can just also add the parameters as literals in the same way. Not pretty but it should work.

Comment: I've found this: _"In SPL routines, a prepared object can include the text of no more than one SQL statement, and that statement must be either an EXECUTE FUNCTION, EXECUTE PROCEDURE, or SELECT statement, but the SELECT statement cannot include the INTO variable, INTO TEMP, or FOR UPDATE clause."_. So it seems you're right, I'll take the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE path. Not pretty indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Dynamic SQL in SPL was added fairly recently — 11.70 or 12.10.  How many different tables do you have that all contain a column `my_field` and have all other columns accepting nulls or with defaults defined?  If you have more than one, I'm dubious about your database design; if you have even one, I'm dubious about that table design.  —— That aside, I'm not clear that the dynamic SQL is really necessary.  I'd probably use one procedure per table.

Comment: A little (emphasis on little) experimentation backs up your observations — the syntax doesn't work yet there's no documentation indicating that it shouldn't work.  That might end up being treated as a documentation error or an implementation oversight.  I hope it'll be the latter.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. The `my_field` column was only an example, but there are more than a dozen tables involved, every one of them with more of a hundred columns, times CRUD. Anyway, it's dynamic SQL so far, with some data manipulation for DATE and VARCHAR columns. And you're right about both DB and table design: Both legacy crap, we're just the guys left to endure them :)